# Get the address with google to excel

Tags: excel, vba, web, web-scraping

I'm trying to navigate to google then write a place like "supermarket X in State Y" then in google appears an photo of the market and the adress below.

SO I wish to set the store in google than take the adress and set it into a Cell in excel.

My only code to this :

```
Sub search()
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
With IE
    .Visible = False
    .Navigate ("https://www.google.com")
While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
.document.getElementById("lst-ib").Value = "vida" ' ID of TextBox of google
.document.all("sblsbb").Click ' ID of the search button of google
End With
```

End Sub

But I got an error is the last line.

Thank's

Comment: You need to check that the IE is not busy, and is READY, VBA doesnt care that IE is loading google

Comment: '   Loop whilst the browser is busy or still loading
    While objIE.Busy Or objIE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Wend

Comment: Then set your text box, and then do the same, but find the search button and btn.Click should do the search.

Comment: Still got erro, the two last lines

Comment: .document.getElementsByClassName("lsb")(0).click is the way, you need to do a bit of investigation, the above is the name of the div containing the button

Comment: "www.google.co.uk/search?sclient=psy-ab&site=&source=hp&q=XXXXYYYYZZZZ" could be a way forward

Answer (score 0):

"Vida" doesn't necessarily bring back a store even on first page.

This will do the search for you then you will need to decide what to do next.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub HitThatSearchButton()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
    Const URL As String = "https://www.google.com/"
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate URL
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        .document.querySelector("#lst-ib").Value = "Vida"
        .document.querySelector("input[value='Google Search']").Click

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Stop                                     '<== Delete me
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```